# C headers in C++ programs

Tags: c++, c, header

I know that C headers can be used in C++ programs by prefixing them with 'c'.
However, I can't figure out why someone would do this. Are there any situations where a C header would be better suited in a c++ program?

Comment: The question isn't entirely clear. Are you talking about using the standard C library via the C++ headers like `<cmath>`? You'd do that where you want to use functions (like those in `<cmath>`) which aren't otherwise available in the C++ standard library.

Comment: C requires names to have C linkage. The declaration syntax of C is valid C++, but C++ does not give names C linkage by default, so you need to wrap C headers in C linkage specifiers.

Comment: This question is a little ambiguous. Are you asking why we'd use the `cX` inherited C headers over the original `X.h` headers? Or why we'd use either in C++ at all? Or why two sets exist in the first place?

Comment: Yes, I was talking about using the C library headers like <cmath>

Answer (score 2):

You often don't need to name your header specially. You could just do

```
extern "C" {
#include "your-c-header.h"
}; // end extern C
```

Or even put in `your-header.h` something like

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/// the real content of your header goes here
#ifndef __cplusplus
}; // end extern C
#endif
```

of course you'll also add the usual [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

The C++ language was originally designed to be C compatible (and even today, C++11 is "mostly" -but not officially- compatible with "most of" C99 or C11). So that trick is *usually* working. But *you* should know the corner cases of incompatibility between C and C++ (it depends upon the particular versions of C and of C++, and perhaps even of your particular implementation and operating system).

BTW, the C++ standard indeed defines some header names like `<cstdio>` but only for wrapping standard C headers (like `<stdio.h>`). For other headers (like POSIX ones, or like those from your favorite library), this does not systematically apply.

As to why is including C headers useful in C++ code: how could you use e.g. standard C APIs (like POSIX) without doing that, or use some available API and library  (e.g. `<readline/readline.h>` or `<gdbm.h>` or `<ncurses.h>` from GNU)?

Comment: unless that header already has 
#ifdef __cplusplus 
extern "C" {
#endif 
etc.

Comment: These aren't the only changes you'll need. You'll need to make sure your cross-usable code declares stuff in a cross compilable way (`typedef struct {} foo;`, ect). In my cross compilable code, I enforce that .h files are C++ and C compatible, while .hpp files are c++ only, but to each their own.

Comment: I know that, this is why I wrote "mostly" and "usually"

Comment: (Btw I plus oned your answer, cuz it is a good answer). Another quick improvement is to answer "why" part of their question.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason to use C headers is to interoperate with some code compiled with C compiler. You can't use C++ headers as they will generate you different symbol names, because of C++ [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

For example, you have a compiled static library and a function defined in C header:

```
void foo(int);
```

The symbol for this function in the static library will be just

```
foo
```

And you're trying to use this library in C++ application, but C++ compiler will look for this symbol (in case of Visual C++)

```
?foo@@YAXH@Z
```

So you'll get a linker error. In order to prevent this error, you need to include this header with `extern C` clause.

Comment: What's "legacy" about C?

Comment: @KerrekSB that was my personal experience. Sorry, already edited.

Comment: It is not only code compiled with the C compiler. Because of the lack of name mangling/it was around longer, many other languages link much more easily to C than C++. C#, matlab, python, (and many more) all have ways to easily call C shared library functions that are not compatable with C++ generated code.